# get numbers from a link html parsing jsoup

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I am working on a software and new on Jsoup. I need help. I am parsing a website. getting links like that :

```
<a href="/?loc=shop_view_item&amp;item=139218679" class="market-name market-link">XXX</a>
```

How can I take numbers "139218679" with Jsoup or regex. Can you help me please?

Comment: show us what you have tried a [MCVE] to demonstrate it. You have to make the effort on your part first.

Comment: I am still tryin. for ex I tried that. String linkk = links.get(2).select("a.market-name.market-link").first().attr("abs:href");

Comment: I tried pattern but it is not working. Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile("/\\d+$/");
                
                
                    Matcher matcher = idPattern.matcher(linkk);
                    
                    while(matcher.find())
                {
                    System.out.println(matcher.group());
                }

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you . What you need is you need to get numbers from the string;

```
String html ="<a href=\"/?loc=shop_view_item&amp;item=139218679\" class=\"market-name market-link\">XXX</a>";

        Document document= Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = document.select("a[href]");

        for (Element element:elements){
            String itemValue = element.attr("href");
            itemValue = itemValue.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
            System.out.println(itemValue.trim());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

example to check from javascript:
`

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("market-name market-link");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
console.log(links[i].href.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
}
```

`

Comment: I am using java and I don't know javascript. can you explain please?

Comment: @CandiceArroyo just get value of a href and try too match it with pattern in my answer.

Comment: But your pattern not working for me. If I use "\\d+" it is working but taking another numbers in link.

Comment: @CandiceArroyo https://regex101.com/r/sgcvVt/1 and try code generator on this page